# Rails override controller layout in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a gem that adds an engine to my Rails app with routes that all render snippets of html using the default application layout.   I want the controller in this gem to use a different layout.  Is there a way I can add code to an initializer that will dynamically cause a controller in a gem to always use a layout.  E.g. can I throw something like the following code (which isn't working) in an initializer assuming the full definition of SampleController is defined in the gem I am using?

```
class SampleController
  layout 'my_layout'
end
```

I know you can call `class_eval` or `instance_eval` for class and instance methods but how to override this type of initialization code?

Comment: You don't need to do any class or instance eval work for this. Your engine should automatically push your engine layout directory onto the view paths stack. Just make sure your engine configuration specifies the directory correctly (note that if you specify one path independently, you need to specify them all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a 'sample.html.haml' (or whichever templating language) in your layouts directory, it will be used instead of application.html for SampleController.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

Comment: Good idea, except that the alternate layout I want to use already exists and is named something else.  If I can't think of anything else I might copy it into "sample.html.haml" and accept this answer.  Thanks.